# Error message using telnet

Tags: postfix, telnet

I am installing postfix. I configured the main.cf with the local ip 127.0.0.1. I created a contact@localhost.fr in my bdd (phpmyadmin). But when I send an email using telnet, I put : rcpt to: and I have a message error "Temporary lookup failure
". So the mail is not sent, what does this message mean exactly ?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the error as shown in the postfix mail log -- for security reasons, Postfix does not reveal all it knows to unauthenticated clients.